# pyqt5での画像の表示が思うようにいかない

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

Python3.5 と PyQt5 で複数の画像をドラッグ&ドロップドロップした時にそれらの画像を下図のように表示するGUIを作りたいです。

しかし、矢印を押しても画像が次の画像に移りません。Buttonクラス内でのimagelistの変更がExampleクラス内でのimagelistに反映されてないのが原因だと思うのですが、どう直せばいいのかが分かりません。

[image: GUI]

**現状のコード:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets

myLabel = None

class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        mimeData = e.mimeData()


        # パスの有無で判定
        if mimeData.hasUrls():
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        # ファイルから画像読込
        urls = e.mimeData().urls()
        path = urls[0].toLocalFile()
        urllength=len(urls)
        imagelist=[]
        for file in range(0,urllength):
            imagelist.append(urls[file].toLocalFile())    
        print(imagelist)
        
        myLabel.setIcon(QIcon(path))



class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.list1=["グリーングリーン.jpg"]
        global imagelist
        imagelist=self.list1
        
        self.listlength=len(imagelist)
        self.imagenumber=0
        iconimage=self.list1[self.imagenumber]
        self.button = Button("",self)
        self.button.resize(400,300)
        self.button.setIcon(QIcon(iconimage)) 
        self.button.setIconSize(QSize(400,300))
        self.button.move(50, 50)

        self.btnright=QPushButton(self)
        self.btnright.resize(40,40)
        self.btnright.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(getattr(QStyle,"SP_ArrowRight")))
        self.btnright.setToolTip('次の画像')
        self.btnright.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.btnright.move(460, 200)  
        self.btnright.clicked.connect(self.stepnext)        
        
        self.btnleft=QPushButton(self)
        self.btnleft.resize(40,40)
        self.btnleft.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(getattr(QStyle,"SP_ArrowLeft")))
        self.btnleft.setToolTip('前の画像')
        self.btnleft.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.btnleft.move(5, 200)  
        self.btnleft.clicked.connect(self.stepprev)

        global myLabel
        myLabel = self.button



        #global imnum
        #imnum=self.imagenumber

        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)


    def stepnext(self):
        print(imagelist)
        if self.imagenumber<self.listlength-1:
            print(imagelist)
            self.imagenumber=self.imagenumber+1
            myLabel.setIcon(QIcon(imagelist[self.imagenumber]))
            
        else:
            pass

    def stepprev(self):
        if self.imagenumber>0:
            self.imagenumber=self.imagenumber-1
            myLabel.setIcon(QIcon(imagelist[self.imagenumber]))
           
        else:
            pass



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Example`クラスの`listlength`メンバ変数を(`imagelist`更新時に)変更していないので、初期値の「1」のまま動作しているからのように見えます。
(そのせいで「次の画像」ボタン操作(`stepnext`メソッド)内のif文が常にfalseになる)

ですので、`imagelist`更新時に`listlength`も合わせて更新するとよいと思います。

Comment: `dropEvent`関数内に`self.listlength=len(imagelist)`を挿入してみましたが変化ありませんでした。どのように直せばよいのでしょうか

Comment: `dropEvent`内の `imagelist`を `global`宣言することで無事解決しました。